# How to split the data into training and testing data

Tags: python, split, datalist

Hi so right now I got data load code and I'm not sure how would i split it into training and testing data. can anyone give me suggestion how to do it this is my data load code.

```
def __init__(self, root, specific_folder, img_extension, preprocessing_method=None, crop_size=(96, 112),train = True):
    """
    Dataloader of the LFW dataset.

    root: path to the dataset to be used.
    specific_folder: specific folder inside the same dataset.
    img_extension: extension of the dataset images.
    preprocessing_method: string with the name of the preprocessing method.
    crop_size: retrieval network specific crop size.
    """

    self.preprocessing_method = preprocessing_method
    self.crop_size = crop_size
    self.imgl_list = []
    self.classes = []
    self.people = []
    self.model_align = None
    self.arr = []

    # read the file with the names and the number of images of each people in the dataset
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'people.txt')) as f:
        people = f.read().splitlines()[1:]

    # get only the people that have more than 20 images
    for p in people:
        p = p.split('\t')
        if len(p) > 1:
            if int(p[1]) >= 20:
                for num_img in range(1, int(p[1]) + 1):
                    self.imgl_list.append(os.path.join(root, specific_folder, p[0], p[0] + '_' +
                                                       '{:04}'.format(num_img) + '.' + img_extension))
                    self.classes.append(p[0])
                    self.people.append(p[0])

    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    self.classes = le.fit_transform(self.classes)

    print(len(self.imgl_list), len(self.classes), len(self.people))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    imgl = imageio.imread(self.imgl_list[index])
    cl = self.classes[index]

    # if image is grayscale, transform into rgb by repeating the image 3 times
    if len(imgl.shape) == 2:
        imgl = np.stack([imgl] * 3, 2)

    imgl, bb = preprocess(imgl, self.preprocessing_method, crop_size=self.crop_size,
                          is_processing_dataset=True, return_only_largest_bb=True, execute_default=True)

    # append image with its reverse
    imglist = [imgl, imgl[:, ::-1, :]]

    # normalization
    for i in range(len(imglist)):
        imglist[i] = (imglist[i] - 127.5) / 128.0
        imglist[i] = imglist[i].transpose(2, 0, 1)
    imgs = [torch.from_numpy(i).float() for i in imglist]

    return imgs, cl, imgl, bb, self.imgl_list[index], self.people[index]

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.imgl_list)
```

I need to split the data in there into 20% and 80% data so I can test my module it been almost a week now and still have no idea at all how to do it would be appreciate so much if anyone can help:

Comment: At first glance I can't find the variable holding your data but it seems you are using sklearn's fit_transform. Have you tried [model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split)? There is more to splitting train data than just taking a portion of it. You need to look at randomization, co-dependence, and many factors. Try searching in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi i try that and when i run it the program keep run and never stop im not sure is this suppose to happen?

Answer (score 0):

In general using PyTorch:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

dataset = yourdatahere
batch_size = 16 #change to whatever you'd like it to be
test_split = .2
shuffle_dataset = True
random_seed= 42

# Creating data indices for training and validation splits:
dataset_size = len(dataset)
indices = list(range(dataset_size))
split = int(np.floor(test_split * dataset_size))
if shuffle_dataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
train_indices, test_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]

# Creating PT data samplers and loaders:
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           sampler=train_sampler)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                sampler=test_sampler)

# Usage Example:
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Train:   
    for batch_index, (faces, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # ...
```

Please note that you should also split your training data into training + validation data. You may use the same logic from above to do so.

Comment: and have another question will the result come in array form ordifferent version

Comment: Just wonder is it possible to let you check my training module and check is this look ok or i need to change something

Comment: if i dont know my batch size are there way to check it? im pretty new to coding sorry for many question

Comment: batch size is a parameter that you choose -- in general, a batch size of 32 is a good starting point. Also, no worries!

Comment: so right now the file i have is not simple. I got folder per person for example I got folder name bob and in there bob photo and another folder name kevin and that contain kevin photo do you have some idea how would i able to open all of the image ?

Comment: you should organize your files such that each folder is a labeled class. an easy example would be if you were doing binary classification on dogs and cats, one folder would contain all your dog photos, another folder would contain all your cat photos.

Comment: yes i got that layout and how would i able to load it

Comment: im very new to code so not sure how to get there :(